# How to use sys.columns to get all columns of only user tables - in a database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2022

I have hundreds of user tables and each tables has lots of columns. [Sys.Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is returning `16000` columns; whereas [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) is returning about `15,000`.

**Question**: Why the above two functions are returning such different counts? Using `Sys.Columns`, how can we get the columns of `ONLY` all user tables in a Database?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM sys.columns --16,000
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS --15,004
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `sp_helptext 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'` you will see `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` joins `sys.columns` to `sys.objects` and only includes columns where the corresponding object is of type 'U' or 'V'.

`sys.colums` includes additional types with the complete list [documented as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

- Table-valued assembly functions (FT)
- Inline table-valued SQL functions (IF)
- Internal tables (IT)
- System tables (S)
- Table-valued SQL functions (TF)
- User tables (U)
- Views (V)

So the following should return the same count

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.object_id = o.object_id
where o.type IN ('U', 'V')
```

Use `o.type = 'U'` if you only want user tables

Comment: @MatinSmith Good explanation (+1).